# DD4T RTF images pre-pended with incorrect path

Tags: dd4t

We are using DD4T on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1. When presenting images from within a RTF we note that the root path is added twice to the image path/filename.

We have configured the web app under a virtual path /vpath/ as read from the webserver variables `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath`.

Images are being presented to the deployed environment as `/vpath/vpath/images/image-name.jpg` - any ideas if we're missing a configuration to indicate the path prefix is not required?

We originally setup the publication with the /vpath part in the URL in the Publications Settings Path and later the requirement (IT team) was to setup the application to run under a virtual directory.

We'd initially thought we could reuse a web.config setting we have to indicate that the application runs under a virtual directory (for other functional requirements)

```
<add key="VirtualDir" value="vpath" />
```

and just update the method to:

```
    public static string AdjustUrlToContext(string url)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VirtualDir"]) 
            return url;

        return HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + url;
    }
```

But we also need to consider if we create another publication and the publication setting does not include the virtual path.

**Update:**

Indeed, the proper solution would be to not have the virtual path in the publication path but given we are stuck where we are right now and need a fix before re-visiting,

we could check if the URL passed in already starts with the `VirtualDir` and then remove it... I don't like the idea of just removing full stop... I know we can 'manage' this going forward by not having the prefix in the publication settings but it assumes too much.

So let's imagine we do have a `/anothersite/anothersite/index.aspx` ... the above code is saying this is simply not allowed as a consequence of a legacy issue. Bad times.

Comment: OK. So I can see in the General class in DD4T.Mvc.Utils that we add context (AdjustUrlToContext) to the URL. It seems that there's no specific config to allow for an application running under a specific virtual directory.

Comment: Have you checked the Images Path setting on the Publication properties in the CME?

Comment: Cheers Nick... was just updating the question after seeing this. One challenge is that the requirements changed and with the site live it was deemed to high-risk to update this value...

Comment: @dylan while I agree that simply changing it on a live environment is indeed too high of a risk (besides the fact that you need to republish the entire website after that, since you changed a value used in all Pages). It could however still be worth investigating that a change on an acceptance environment, as leaving it incorrectly set might cause you more problems in the future.

Comment: @Bart - Absolutely correct. We have requested time from the client to retrospectively investigate this once we have the current 'live' issue of rendering images correctly resolved. Much better to bite-the-bullet now and resolve than when the site is 10x bigger (or someone else copies the same, incorrect, format on another publication/site)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For information...

As this is specific to a 'legacy' post-implementation issue that we can't simply reverse without a full site re-test etc. we have opted for the following solution.

If we have a `VirtualDir` setting in the web.config we also include a simple (albeit verbose) `VirtualDirIncludedInPubSettings` value which we can set to true if we want to execute a snippet to remove the prefix if it's (retrospectively incorrectly) added.

This solves the problem now, allows for future sites to be configured 'correctly' and also allows us to correct this site and just tweak the config when time permits.